# How can I access UIPickerView in a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have been learning iOS dev and run into a problem.
I have a class which has a `UIPickerView` as follows (It is hidden to begin with)

```
public class MyController: UIViewController, 
                           UIPickerViewDelegate, 
                           UITableViewDataSource, 
                           UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myPickerView: UIPickerView!
}
```

I have another class where I need to access this picker view and make it visible when the user starts editing a text field (which has a tag = 2)

```
public class MyClass2: UITableViewCell, 
                       UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet vat myTextField: UITextField! {didSet {myTextField.delegate = self } }
public func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  if (textField.tag == 2) {
    // Somehow access the picker view from the other class and change its property, hidden, to false
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should read up on protocols and delegation; then set your view controller as the delegate when you create the cell and have the cell call the delegate method as required

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instance for your activeViewController in MyClass2,

```
static var activeViewController: UIViewController
```

When you are working on your MyController, set activeViewController

```
MyClass2.activeViewController = self
```

Finally, you'll change anything in MyController class using activeViewController,

```
if let myController = activeViewController as? MyController {
   //Do something with your PickerView
   myController.myPickerView = ...
}
```